# FreeNAS is getting Uncorrectable parity/CRC errors

Tags: hard-drive, freebsd, log-files, truenas, smart

In my FreeNAS 9.3 installation I am getting more and more Uncorrectable parity/CRC errors (like these here:

```
May 15 13:39:41 freenas (ada1:ahcich1:0:0:0): READ_FPDMA_QUEUED. ACB: 60 00 b8 0e 18 40 91 00 00 01 00 00
May 15 13:39:41 freenas (ada1:ahcich1:0:0:0): CAM status: Uncorrectable parity/CRC error
May 15 13:39:41 freenas (ada1:ahcich1:0:0:0): Retrying command
May 15 13:39:41 freenas (ada1:ahcich1:0:0:0): READ_FPDMA_QUEUED. ACB: 60 00 68 10 18 40 91 00 00 01 00 00
May 15 13:39:41 freenas (ada1:ahcich1:0:0:0): CAM status: Uncorrectable parity/CRC error
May 15 13:39:41 freenas (ada1:ahcich1:0:0:0): Retrying command
May 15 13:39:41 freenas (ada1:ahcich1:0:0:0): READ_FPDMA_QUEUED. ACB: 60 00 18 12 18 40 91 00 00 01 00 00
May 15 13:39:41 freenas (ada1:ahcich1:0:0:0): CAM status: Uncorrectable parity/CRC error
```

at first I changed two disks with these mentionegs - but now one of my newest disks (on another port) is getting these too. 
So I am really sure this drive has no problems at all.

What can cause these Errors? We don't have ECC Ram in this Server...

In the S.M.A.R.T. Log is nothing pointing to problems, so I am confused:

```
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0


SMART Error Log Version: 1                                
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1           
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2398         -
```

Comment: Disk or controller failure.

Comment: what would you suggest? changing cables / controllers and disks?

Answer (score 3):

You have a disk, controller or cable failure.

You have not provided any details on the hardware involved in this solution. The is not a RAM issue, but treat this like any other troubleshooting effort:

- This is impacting multiple disks.
- SMART reporting on the disks show no errors... But they *are* SATA...
- Investigate how the disks are connected? Via backplane? Via combined fan-out cables?
- This sounds like SATA gear. Did you change cables?
- What is your controller reporting?
- Did you [**google the error string**](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=CAM%20status:%20Uncorrectable%20parity/CRC%20error&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) you've been receiving?